# Avoid text wrapping during slideUp?

Tags: jquery, slideup

My goal is to create a simple sliding animation that will show/hide a paragraph of text when a button is pressed. See jsfiddle below. There is also a thumbnail image, which is always visible, and around which the text wraps. Now, when I use jQuery slideUp to hide the text, the wrapping of the text first changes (as if overflow was temporarily set to hidden), and then animation runs. Specifically, in the example below, the text moves to the right into one narrow column before vanishing. How can I achieve that the text does not move at all during the animation? All I want is that it vanishes from bottom to top, without re-wrapping.

The jQuery code:

```
$("div.thumbnail").click(function () {
    $("p").slideToggle();
});
```

Full example in jsfiddle (click on the square to toggle slide): http://jsfiddle.net/p2mxp5ec/4/

Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably have to wrap it in a container div with `overflow: hidden` and slideUp the container.  That should keep the inner tags from changing layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to wrap your entire content in a container and create a false thumbnail.

```js
$("div.thumbnail").click(function() {
  $(".thumbTextContainer").slideToggle();

});
```

```css
 div.pseudoThumbnail {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 2px solid;
   float: left;
 }
 .thumbnail {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 2px solid;
   position: absolute;
 }
 .container {
   position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>

  <div class="thumbTextContainer">
    <div class="pseudoThumbnail"></div>
    <p class="myText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac velit gravida odio bibendum molestie. In tristique libero et ante interdum, sit amet vestibulum massa lacinia. Mauris massa neque, congue eget nisl sit amet, lacinia consequat metus.
      Duis euismod turpis nec accumsan hendrerit. Cras fermentum placerat massa at imperdiet. Pellentesque vulputate fringilla nulla quis lobortis. Curabitur luctus neque leo, eu porttitor tortor iaculis eu. Vivamus rhoncus consequat egestas. Nam eu odio
      vitae ligula commodo congue at in risus. Nunc id efficitur nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac velit gravida odio bibendum molestie. In tristique libero et ante interdum, sit amet vestibulum massa lacinia. Mauris
      massa neque, congue eget nisl sit amet, lacinia consequat metus. Duis euismod turpis nec accumsan hendrerit. Cras fermentum placerat massa at imperdiet. Pellentesque vulputate fringilla nulla quis lobortis. Curabitur luctus neque leo, eu porttitor
      tortor iaculis eu. Vivamus rhoncus consequat egestas. Nam eu odio vitae ligula commodo congue at in risus. Nunc id efficitur nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac velit gravida odio bibendum molestie. In tristique
      libero et ante interdum, sit amet vestibulum massa lacinia. Mauris massa neque, congue eget nisl sit amet, lacinia consequat metus. Duis euismod turpis nec accumsan hendrerit. Cras fermentum placerat massa at imperdiet. Pellentesque vulputate fringilla
      nulla quis lobortis. Curabitur luctus neque leo, eu porttitor tortor iaculis eu. Vivamus rhoncus consequat egestas. Nam eu odio vitae ligula commodo congue at in risus. Nunc id efficitur nisl.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```